# Can't get detox to find iPhone X or simulators older than iPhone 11

Tags: detox

Getting this error after accepting the licensing from XCode for upgrading with iOS 13 and iPhone 11. I have no problem running the detox tests against an iPhone 11 device using "iPhone 11" as the name value in the detox configuration.

Error: Can't find a simulator to match with "iPhone X", run 'xcrun simctl list' to list your supported devices.
       It is advised to only state a device type, and not to state iOS version, e.g. "iPhone 7"```

ran `xcrun simctl list` and iPhone X is definietly in there and booted:

````
iPhone 4s (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-4s)
iPhone 5 (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-5)
iPhone 5s (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-5s)
iPhone 6 Plus (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-6-Plus)
iPhone 6 (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-6)
iPhone 6s (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-6s)
iPhone 6s Plus (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-6s-Plus)
iPhone SE (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-SE)
iPhone 7 (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-7)
iPhone 7 Plus (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-7-Plus)
iPhone 8 (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-8)
iPhone 8 Plus (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-8-Plus)
iPhone X (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-X)
iPhone Xs (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-XS)
iPhone Xs Max (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-XS-Max)
iPhone Xʀ (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-XR)
iPhone 11 (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-11)
iPhone 11 Pro (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-11-Pro)
iPhone 11 Pro Max (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-11-Pro-Max)
...
```-- iOS 12.2 --
    iPhone 5s (B9F8AD52-F3A4-4E5A-B6EC-406827678E41) (Shutdown) 
    iPhone 6 Plus (D5C54611-B44F-4F42-A400-FA6B3F10877A) (Shutdown) 
    iPhone 6 (E29542E6-163D-4ABD-8825-78975A22934D) (Shutdown) 
    iPhone 6s (B6D65541-1EB4-43A7-B738-28A215AE50D4) (Shutdown) 
    iPhone 6s Plus (C1C0488F-7810-4552-B404-F344D36B1215) (Shutdown) 
    iPhone 7 (7A5DDC90-60BD-4B9A-9CEC-62C924EB86DF) (Shutdown) 
    iPhone 7 Plus (D19DABA8-AA67-454D-904E-760D202A148A) (Shutdown) 
    iPhone 8 (37F662FE-7368-46E2-AE87-4C1EC561DB07) (Shutdown) 
    iPhone 8 Plus (E7F29F60-E1E3-4206-875C-CE0CD0FDD2B5) (Shutdown) 
    iPhone X (13DD7A53-D818-444D-A537-633365C9DFA8) (Booted) ```
Did detox drop support for running against other iPhone simulators?

I've updated applesimutils and removed and re-added the iPhone X device with iOS version 12.2, but still same error.
````

Comment: Upgrade your applesimutils. To check it works, run `applesimutils --list`

Comment: Thanks I tried that too, but my problem was I didn't have an iPhone X with the latest version of iOS (13 in this case)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix for me is here: https://github.com/wix/Detox/issues/1675

Coyping solution here as well:
"Setting the name for the simulator in the Detox config to "iPhone 5s,iOS 11.3" vs "iPhone 5s" fixed it for me. It seems deviceInfo.newestRuntime.version in Detox's AppleSimUtils.js will return the latest OS version despite whether a simulator exists for that version or not."

Answer (score 2):

I have also faced this issue and resolved it with the below command.

1. brew tap wix/brew
2. brew install applesimutils

Also, I am using XCode 12.4 and detox 18.7.1.

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing the same behavior with Detox 14.3.4. I'm assuming that is the version of Detox that you're using.

Comment: Yes I am on the latest version of detox. Someone did find a solution and I posted here. Hope it helps you too

Answer (score 0):

Detox was recently updated with new device selection API in package.json. Please migrate to that.